# Which is best chart for intraday trading & how to use it?

Tags: trading, intraday, charts, trading-patterns

I have new learner & want to make trading as my full time work. I read some articles on charts, that helps to buy or sell shares. Pls tell me, how to read charts & buy or sell shares using that.

Comment: You are asking this question in the wrong forum. Not many here who read charts.

Comment: OK can I change the forum now ?

Comment: I think I should delete this post. I will wait then delete since I can edit everything but forum. Sorry